# System modify all data permission does not seem to be working

Tags: permissions, exception, permission-sets, system-permissions

I am trying to update activities (tasks) using the bulk API utilizing a client. It seems to be working however I am getting a few thousand records that are returning an error :

```
Unknown_Exception: An unknown exception has occurred.
```

I then viewed a few of the tasks in the UI and they all seem to have 1 custom object (Practice) in the whatId field of the task.

Also logged on as a super admin, I am seeing the following:

[image]

I tried editing it under my user and it said the same error.

```
Unknown_Exception: An unknown exception has occurred.
```

So thinking it is a permission issue, I then went to the permission setting (IC User) assigned to my bulk API client user and went to:

1). Permission Set Overview -> Object Settings -> Practice custom object,  and did the following settings:

[image]

2). Permission Set Overview->System Permissions, and did Modify All Data along with Access activities

Overkill I know but even with the following I am unable to modify tasks that have Practice Custom object as the WhatId.  Now if I take one record and remove the Related To/What Id field either in UI or Anonymous Apex, I am able to then run the job successfully.

What am I missing?